# How can I extract a specific array in a numpy nested array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm not sure how to figure this out as I'm not familiar with numpy compared to pandas. I have a nested array and I would like to extract a specific column. For example. Give this dataframe:

```
MPG Cylinders   Displacement    Horsepower  Weight  Acceleration    Model Year  Origin  NumpyColumn
0   18.0    8   307.0   130.0   3504.0  12.0    70  1   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
1   15.0    8   350.0   165.0   3693.0  11.5    70  1   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
2   18.0    8   318.0   150.0   3436.0  11.0    70  1   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
3   16.0    8   304.0   150.0   3433.0  12.0    70  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
4   17.0    8   302.0   140.0   3449.0  10.5    70  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
393 27.0    4   140.0   86.0    2790.0  15.6    82  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
394 44.0    4   97.0    52.0    2130.0  24.6    82  2   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
395 32.0    4   135.0   84.0    2295.0  11.6    82  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
396 28.0    4   120.0   79.0    2625.0  18.6    82  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
397 31.0    4   119.0   82.0    2720.0  19.4    82  1   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

if I want to separate the nested array from the other items I would do this:

```
everthingExceptNumpyArray = df.drop('NumpyColumn',1).to_numpy()
onlyNumpyArray = np.array(df['NumpyColumn'].tolist())
```

but I'm not sure how to do this if the above df is already a numpy array. So given:

```
array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 9921.0,
       20.0, 0.40457918757980704, 0.11369258150627903, 0.868421052631579,
       0.47368421052631576, 0.894736842105263, 0.06688034531010473,
       0.16160188713280013, 0.7368421052631579, 0.1673332894736842,
       0.2099143206854345, 0.3690644464300929, 0.07097828135799109,
       0.8157894736842104, 0.9210526315789473, 0.23091420289239645,
       0.08623506024464939, 0.5789473684210527, 0.763157894736842, 0.0,
       0.18421052631578946, 0.07949239000059796, 0.18763907099960708,
       0.7368421052631579, 0.2668740256483197, 0.6842105263157894,
       0.13699219747488295, 0.868421052631579, 0.868421052631579,
       0.052631349139178094, 0.6842105263157894, 0.5526315789473684,
       0.6842105263157894, 0.6842105263157894, 0.6842105263157894,
       0.7105263157894737, 0.7105263157894737, 0.7105263157894737,
       0.23684210526315788, 0.0, 0.7105263157894737, 0.5789473684210527,
       0.763157894736842, 0.5263157894736842, 0.6578947368421052,
       0.6842105263157894, 0.7105263157894737, 0.0, 0.5789473684210527,
       0.2631578947368421, 0.6842105263157894, 0.6578947368421052,
       0.42105263157894735, 0.5789473684210527, 0.42105263157894735,
       0.7368421052631579, 0.7368421052631579, 0.15207999030227856,
       0.8445892232119124, 0.2683721567016762, 0.3142850329243405,
       0.18421052631578946, 0.19132292433056333, 0.20615136344079915,
       0.14475710664724623, 0.1624920232728424, 0.6989826700898587,
       0.18421052631578946, 0.21052631578947367, 0.4793448772543646,
       0.7894736842105263, 0.682967263567459, 0.37139592674256894,
       0.21123755190149363, 0.18421052631578946, 0.6578947368421052,
       0.39473684210526316, 0.631578947368421, 0.7894736842105263,
       0.36842105263157887, 0.1863353145721346, 0.7368421052631579,
       0.26809396092240706, 0.22492185003691062, 0.1460488284639197,
       0.631578947368421, 0.15347526114630458, 0.763157894736842,
       0.2097323620058104, 0.3684210526315789, 0.631578947368421,
       0.631578947368421, 0.631578947368421, 0.6842105263157894,
       0.36842105263157887, 0.10507952765043811, 0.22418515695024185,
       0.23755698619020282, 0.22226500126902, 0.530004040377794,
       0.3421052631578947, 0.19018711711349692, 0.19629244102133708,
       0.5789473684210527, 0.10526315789473684, 0.49999999999999994,
       0.5263157894736842, 0.5263157894736842, 0.49999999999999994,
       0.1052631578947368, 0.10526315789473678, 0.5263157894736842,
       0.4736842105263157, 2013.0,
       array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.62235785, 0.        ,
       0.27049118, 0.        , 0.31094068, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.4330532 , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.2515796 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.40683705, 0.01569915, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.13090582, 0.        , 0.49955425, 0.06970194, 0.29155406,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.27342197, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.04415211, 0.        , 0.03908829, 0.        ,
       0.07673171, 0.33199945, 0.        , 0.51759815, 0.        ,
       0.4719149 , 0.4538082 , 0.13475986, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.08000553,
       0.        , 0.02991109, 0.        , 0.5051543 , 0.        ,
       0.24663273, 0.        , 0.50839704, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.05281948, 0.44884402, 0.        , 0.44542992, 0.15376966,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.39128256, 0.49497205,
       0.        , 0.        ], dtype=float32)
```

What can I do to get a similar result as above but if the data is already a NumPy array?

Comment: `np.array(a[:,:-1].tolist())`?

Comment: @QuangHoang np.array(a[:,:-1].tolist()) worked for getting the last nested array. How do I query to get the part of the arrays before that in a similar fashion? I'm not 100% how this command works. Also can you add your answer as a answer so I can accept it?

Comment: `df['NumpyColumn']` is a Series with object dtype, and an array in each element.  (though they could also be lists or even strings - the display is the same.)  `tolist` should give a list of arrays.  `np.stack(....tolist()` may be able to join them into one 2d array (if they all match in shape).

Comment: @hpaulj good point. I think the nested array sometimes doesn't match in size. It's either the same size or NaN.  Do you have a example? or what I should look up, I've been using pandas much more instead of numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a sample dataframe:

```
In [61]: data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.array([3,4])],[5,6,np.array([7,8])]])
In [62]: data
Out[62]: 
   0  1       2
0  1  2  [3, 4]
1  5  6  [7, 8]
In [63]: data[2]
Out[63]: 
0    [3, 4]
1    [7, 8]
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

The `numpy` array extraction of the series:

```
In [65]: data[2].to_numpy()
Out[65]: array([array([3, 4]), array([7, 8])], dtype=object)
```

and list version:

```
In [66]: data[2].to_list()
Out[66]: [array([3, 4]), array([7, 8])]
```

If all those subarrays have the same shape we can combine them with `stack` (or `vstack`):

```
In [67]: np.stack(data[2].to_list())
Out[67]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [7, 8]])
```

and a more obnoxious mix of elements

```
In [71]: data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.array([3,4])],[5,6,[7,8]],[10,11,"[12, 13]
    ...: "],[12,13,np.nan]])
In [72]: data
Out[72]: 
    0   1         2
0   1   2    [3, 4]
1   5   6    [7, 8]
2  10  11  [12, 13]
3  12  13       NaN
In [73]: data[2].to_list()
Out[73]: [array([3, 4]), [7, 8], '[12, 13]', nan]
```

Note that the dataframe display doesn't give much indication of the different types.